# what is the difference between dijit.byId('someId').value and dijit.byId('someId').get('value')

Tags: javascript, dojo

When I am doing the validation at client side for one of my application. I got these questions in my mind.

Question1 : what is the difference between dijit.byId('someId').value and dijit.byId('someId').get('value')

Question2:

```
for(indx in strg){
        comment+=strg[indx].replace(/([^\x00-\x7E]|\\s*\\n)*$/g, '');
    }
```

In the above js snippet, I got the following error in Browser console

```
replace is not a function
```

Can you please help me someone to solve this

Thanks.

Comment: Please keep your questions to one question per post.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your first part of you question.

dijit.byId('id'); has been **deprecated**, you should use `dijit/registry::byId()` instead.

`registry.byId()` will return a widget with same ID if found.

You can use it in your application in this way:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    var widget = registry.byId("yourId");
});
```

You can read a property for a widget using `widget.get('nameProperty')`, example:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    var widget = registry.byId("yourId");
    var widgetValue = widget.get('value');
});
```

Generally accessing properties of your widget should be done using "getter" and "setter". Dojo offer two dedicated functions for that:

Getter: 
 `widget.get('nameProperty');`

Setter:
 `widget.get('nameProperty', 'newValue');`

When using getter and setter you allow dojo to be aware of those operations, for example when using a setter, dojo events fire properly (like onChange for your widget).

In case you  access/set a property directly on the widget you bypass dojo, missing is framework plumbing.

More information:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html